# How do I refer to a variable in an async method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`await sendEmail (req.body.email, this.verificationCode)` throws an error:

> this.verificationCode = undefined

How can I fix this?

```
class VerificationCodeController{

  constructor(){
    this.verificationCode = generateCode()
  }

  async sendCode(req, res){
    await sendEmail(req.body.email, this.verificationCode)
    return res.json(responseCreator.response(this.verificationCode));
  }

}
```

Comment: where is the generateCode()? is it inside the class?

Comment: And what is `generateCode` actually returning because it looks like it's not returning anything.

Comment: generateCode() not inside class and returning return Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000)

Comment: [I can't duplicate that error](https://jsfiddle.net/ou5b91mp/).

Comment: Can you actually show generateCode? Seeing is believing :)

Comment: const generateCode = (function () {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000)
})